# how should i deselect the chekbox that is already selected in html page using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have checkboxes in my html as follows,

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{fruit.name}} ng-model="fruit.value" 
         ng-checked="isChecked(fruit)" ng-change="changed(fruit)" ng-required="true" ">{{fruit.name}}
</div>
<input type="hidden" ng-model="selectedFruits">
```

And I have angular js code as follows,

```
    $scope.fruits=[{name:"Mango", value:false},{name:"Apple", value:false},{name:"Banana", value:false}];
var array=["Apple","Banana"];
$scope.isChecked = function(fruit){
     for(var I=0; I <array.length; I++){
              if(fruit.name == array[I]){
                 fruit.value=true;
              }
           }  
}
$scope.changed= function(fruit){
   var selectFruit ='';
   $scope.fruits.forEach(function(fruit){   
      if(fruit.value){
         if(selectFruit){
            selectFruit += '-';
         }
         selectFruit += fruit.name;
      }
   })
   $scope.selectedFruits = selectFruit;
}
```

And that hidden field is for appending the selected checkboxes name in "selectedFruits ". [Ex. Mango-Apple]

From above code I'm getting by default selected checkboxes in html page as Apple and Banana that is in an array.

My question is when I'm trying to deselect that checkboxes (Apple/banana), it does not gets deselected . It always shows selected only.
How should I deselect that checkboxes?
Can someone please help me?

Comment: `ng-model="fruit.value" `

Comment: Sorry..I put by mistake {{}} in ng-model. I was using ng-model="fruit.value" only.

Comment: Can you please see that again if any other changes required? @Satpal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make some changes in HTML:
Here

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{fruit.name}} ng-model="fruit.value" 
         ng-click="isChecked(fruit)" required>{{fruit.name}}
</div>
<input type="hidden" ng-model="selectedFruits">
```

**EDIT**

```
var array=["Apple","Banana"];
   for(var I=0; I <array.length; I++){
      if(fruit.name == array[I]){
         fruit.value=true;
      }
   }
```

Put this content outside the checked function or create a new function and put this code in that and call it wherever you want

**EDIT-2**

```
selectAppleBanana();
function selectAppleBanana(){
  for(var I=0; I <array.length; I++){
     for(var J=0;J<$scope.fruits;J++){
         if($scope.fruits[J].name == array[I]){
            $scope.fruits[J].value=true;
         }
     }
   }    
}
$scope.isChecked = function(fruit){
   //don't call it here otherwise it won't get deselected ever
   //selectAppleBanana();
   var selectFruit ='';
   $scope.fruits.forEach(function(fruit){   
      if(fruit.value){
         if(selectFruit){
            selectFruit += '-';
         }
         selectFruit += fruit.name;
      }
   })
   $scope.selectedFruits = selectFruit;
}
```

Comment: With ng-click I'm not getting by default selected checkboxes for Apple and banana. When I load the page no checkbox gets selected.

Comment: Nope..not working ..not showing by default checkboxes and after selecting not appending to that hidden field too

Comment: Answering to this "My question is when I'm trying to deselect that checkboxes (Apple/banana), it does not gets deselected . It always shows selected only. How should I deselect that checkboxes? Can someone please help me?" I have updated EDIT-2, All other things do as you were doing earlier by yourself

Comment: every time you change something isChecked is getting called, it doesn't matter what you're doing(select/deselecting apple,banana) but isChecked will update it to checked only. Either implement my last edit or remove ng-checked.

Comment: With your second edit I'm not getting Apple and banana as selected checkboxes.All are getting deselected. I used the same code as yours.

Comment: create a jsfiddle I'll update and make it work for you.